# Issue with displaying DFT output with openCV's imshow

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I was following the tutorial on [this website](http://datahacker.rs/opencv-discrete-fourier-transform-part2) to create a low-pass filter using NumPy and OpenCV in python. Instead of displaying the transformed image using pyplot as shown in the tutorial, I tried using OpenCV's imshow function but I am not getting the desired output.

```
img = cv2.imread('./lenna.jpg', 0)
img = np.array(img)


dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

rows, cols = img.shape
crow,ccol = int(rows/2) , int(cols/2)

mask = np.zeros((rows,cols,2),np.uint8)
mask[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1

fshift = dft_shift*mask
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])

cv2.imshow('before', img)
cv2.imshow('after', img_back)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Is the output image of the wrong datatype?

[image: output that I'm getting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV's FFT functions require the scaling flag `DFT_SCALE` given to exactly one of `dft,idft`. see the Note at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa708aa2d2e57a508f968eb0f69aa5ff1

I've chosen to pass it in the first function because that already takes the other flag.

numpy's fft2 functions don't need this. they work as is.

here are both versions, only differing in `dft/idft` and `fft2/ifft2`.

```py
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def prepare_spectrum(spectrum):
    mag = np.linalg.norm(spectrum, axis=2)
    mag /= mag.max()
    mag **= 1/4

    return mag

img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"), cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = img / np.float32(255)

dft = cv.dft(img, flags=cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT | cv.DFT_SCALE)

cv.imshow("1 dft", prepare_spectrum(dft))

dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

cv.imshow("2 dft_shift", prepare_spectrum(dft_shift))

rows, cols = img.shape
crow,ccol = (rows // 2), (cols // 2)

mask = np.zeros((rows,cols,2), dtype=np.uint8)
mask[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1

dft_shift *= mask

cv.imshow("3 dft_shift masked", prepare_spectrum(dft_shift))

dft = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift)

cv.imshow("4 dft masked", prepare_spectrum(dft))

img_back = cv.idft(dft)

img_back = img_back[:,:,0] # real part

cv.imshow('before', img)
cv.imshow('after', img_back)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Numpy:

```py
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def prepare_spectrum(spectrum):
    mag = np.abs(spectrum)
    mag /= mag.max()
    mag **= 1/4

    return mag

img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"), cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = img / np.float32(255)

dft = np.fft.fft2(img)

cv.imshow("1 dft", prepare_spectrum(dft))

dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

cv.imshow("2 dft_shift", prepare_spectrum(dft_shift))

rows, cols = img.shape
crow,ccol = (rows // 2), (cols // 2)

mask = np.zeros((rows,cols), dtype=np.uint8)
mask[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1

dft_shift *= mask

cv.imshow("3 dft_shift masked", prepare_spectrum(dft_shift))

dft = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift)

cv.imshow("4 dft masked", prepare_spectrum(dft))

img_back = np.fft.ifft2(dft)

img_back = np.real(img_back)

cv.imshow('before', img)
cv.imshow('after', img_back)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: spectrum masked]
[image: lowpassed lena]

Answer (score 2):

`imshow` expects floats to be in the range of 0 .. 1 to be displayed properly (or uint8 in the range of 0..255).

do this for reading the image:

```py
img = cv2.imread('./lenna.jpg')
img = img / np.float32(255)
```

I would advise against `cv2.normalize` with NORM_MINMAX because that changes the picture's global contrast, which is not what you need (or want).

further, I would advise to get the real component of the complex result. don't take the magnitude.

Comment: Why is taking the real component preferred over taking the magnitude?

Comment: you pass purely real-valued complex numbers into the FFT, so that's the component you should take out of it. imagine giving it negative reals, or expecting negative reals to return? when you take the magnitude of those, you get the absolute value, which is positive, and that would be a mistake when the value is actually negative.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! But the solution you provided doesn't seem to be giving the correct output on my example.

Comment: ah I see the problem. FFT and scale factors... I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display data in type np.float32 you have to normalize it to 1.0

```
img_back = cv2.normalize(img_back, None, alpha=0, beta=1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```